# Error in SQL while updating through webpage

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update my table named 'FA1' through a webpage.
The code used for this is:

```
foreach($columns as $item)
{
    $sqlAtt = " update ". $class ." set ". $item ." = 'P' where `date` = '". $date ."' ";
    $resultAtt = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$sqlAtt);
    if (!$resultAtt) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($GLOBALS['con']));
        exit();
    }
}
```

`$columns` are the column names of the table. `$class` is the table name and `$date` has today's date.

While updating through SQL command executing space inside the database the result is,

```
1 row affected. (Query took 0.0002 seconds.)
update FA1 set FA14 = 'P' where `date` = '2017-05-22'
```

while updating through the webpage what I got is:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'P' where `date` = '2017-05-22'' at line 1

If I output $sqlAtt :

```
update FA1 set FA14
= 'P' where `date` = '2017-05-22' update FA1 set FA11
= 'P' where `date` = '2017-05-22
```

Comment: If you output `$sqlAtt`, what is it?

Comment: update FA1 set FA14
= 'P' where `date` = '2017-05-22' update FA1 set FA11
= 'P' where `date` = '2017-05-22

Comment: Do `exit($sqlAtt);` in the error handling so we know which query errors.

Comment: Why are there 2 queries there?

Comment: Why you need to run the query in a loop. It only updates same records everytime.

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
= 'P' where `date` = '2017-05-22'' at line 1 update FA1 set FA14
= 'P' where `date` = '2017-05-22'

Comment: @AjayVictor You are trying to run 2 queries at once. That is not allowed with the `mysqli_query` function.

Comment: @chris85, it's because he did it in for each loop for updating same set of records

Comment: Actually the column name is changing.. I want to update all the columns except one column..

Comment: @manian No, look at the assignment. `$sqlAtt = ` would overwrite the previous set value. The `$item` is being changed on every iteration.

Comment: @chris85,  only column is changing but not the condition. So everytime it is the same records. he could have updated it in single query.

Comment: @manian It is a single query. We are talking about 2 different things. You are talking about improving the code, I'm talking about the cause of the current error/failure.

Comment: @chris85 Yes What I need is a solution for this error..

Comment: Try trim( $item) in your query. It looks from your output like the column name contains some additional spaces.

Comment: @AjayVictor Debug your code and find how/where that second query is coming from. Something is not right here. The assignment should overwrite every time, unless this is not your exact code.

Comment: How is `$columns` being generated?

Comment: $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ". $class ." LIKE '%". $class ."%'";

    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $columns[] = $row['Field']."<br>";
      
     }

Comment: @CodeGodie Thanks alot your question just answered by question. The <br> did all these issues! Thank You.... :)

Comment: The `<br>` wouldn't have caused the 2 queries. Since it was a typo, not a p a programming issue I'd say you can delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have some type of a line break when creating your `$columns` array which breaks your query, I'd look into that first.

However, `UPDATE` lets you change multiple columns in one query in a "column=value" comma separated style. By doing it this way, your performance will increase as you'd only be running one single query as opposed to the multiple queries youre currently running (one per iteration). This is the format you should aim for:

```
UPDATE tbl SET 
  col1 = 'P',
  col2 = 'P'
```

Do it in this manner:

```
foreach ($columns as $item) {
    $sets[] = trim($item) ." = 'P'";
}
$query = "UPDATE $class SET " . implode(',', $sets) . " WHERE `date` = '$date' ";
$resultAtt = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'], $query);
if (!$resultAtt) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($GLOBALS['con']));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to explain. Its very hard to add/edit code block's from my mobile.

Answer (score 1):

From the output query that you posted, it looks like there are some additional spaces in the column names. Please try to trim your column names like below,

```
$sqlAtt = " update ". $class ." set ". trim($item) ." = 'P' where `date` = '". $date ."' ";
```

To check the values in $item, try var_dump($item).

Comment: Look at the query that is erring. `update FA1 set FA14
= 'P' where \`date\` = '2017-05-22' update FA1 set FA11
= 'P' where \`date\` = '2017-05-22`, That is **2** queries.

Comment: Not working still it shows as:-  Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
= 'P' where `date` = '2017-05-22'' at line 1 update FA1 set FA14
= 'P' where `date` = '2017-05-22'